# Is there anyway to make a reference UNIQUE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to insert a reference from one table to another but I need the reference to be UNIQUE. As the data can only appear once in that table.

`CREATE TABLE 1 (
id     NUMBER,
obj1 REF obj1_typ REFERENCES obj1_tab UNIQUE,
obj2 REF obj2_typ REFERENCES obj2_objtab UNIQUE);`

Comment: If the uniqueness is for table 1 you can create an unique index on table 1 (obj1), and the same for obj2

Comment: How would i go about doing that? can you give examples?

Comment: if table name is one: `create unique index uk_obj1 on one(obj1)`

Answer (score 3):

A foreign key can be declared in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(   product_id  numeric(10) not null,
supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
  FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
  REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id)
);
```

where supplier_id is Primary Key in its table:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
(   supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
supplier_name   varchar2(50)    not null,
contact_name    varchar2(50),   
CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);
```

If you want to ensure that obj1 is unique in the table ONE, you can create a unique key on this column, or simply create an unique index:

```
create unique index uk_obj1 on one(obj1)
```